# How to publish Magento 2 paid module

Tags: magento2, module, package

I have developed one module for old magento versions and now I have developed the same module for Magento 2.

Now, I want to upload this magento 2 module in magento community. I have prepared the required zip file to be uploaded in magento community.

Can anyone help me to do this after this step?

Comment: https://marketplace.magento.com/contacts or mail marketplace@magento.com or https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/extension/extension/add/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Magento have launched its **Marketplace**. You can upload your **Magento 1 & Magento 2 Modules**. Here are the steps

Create account at **marketplace.Magento.com**
Fill out the basic account information
Under **My Products**  click on "Add" button to upload your Module

**Magento marketplace** has **3 steps verification**

**1st Step:** Business review - takes 2-3 days
Provide detail on why your module is unique and should be added on Marketplace

**2nd Step:** Upload Package for Technical Review

**3rd Step:**  Provide Marketing Data - 
Marketing data includes , product images, content and demo information

Comment: After creating an account in marketplace.magento.com, I am not able to see "My Products". Can you tell me where I can get it?

Comment: @GauravAgrawal i added the complete guideline follow here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153746/how-to-publish-magento-2-paid-module/153749#153749